# Is there a solution to automatically synchronize Emacs org-mode with one of the web based todo services?

Tags: web-services, emacs, synchronization, org-mode

Org-mode is amazing. I like its power and simplicity. However, sometimes I need access to my tasks in places where I don't have the necessary setup. Is there a way to synchronize my org agenda with one of the better web based todo services like RTM, Toodledo or similar?

It would be the best solution, because I'd run the sync process regularly and automatically on my computer and I would have access (read access is enough) to my org data through the web interface of the synchronized service.

Answer (score 17):

I have been using Org-mode with Remember the Milk quite nicely.  here is my setup:

```
(require org-feed)
(setq org-feed-alist
      '(("Remember The Milk"
         "https://www.rememberthemilk.com/rss/jonnay/"
         "~/org/GTD.org"
         "Remember The Milk"
         :template "* TODO %title\n  %a\n "
         )))

;;* rtm feed timer
(run-at-time 3600 3600 'org-feed-update-all)
```

The only problem is that I get asked for authentication the first time I start up emacs.  With a bit of elisp this could be fixed, I just haven't had time yet.

Just as an update, there is a new package shaping up that might handle syncing a little better:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/gsoc2012/student-projects/org-sync/index.html

Comment: This is very cool, but what about syncing your org files back up to RTM?

Comment: @Jonathan is that added to your `.emacs`?

Comment: I stopped using RTM awhile ago, so ... no.

Comment: @Jonathan: so is this a method to export RTM to use in the GTD.org org-mode file?

Comment: @Jonathan, With your code, I get the error: `Symbol's value as variable is void: org-feed`; I don't think `(require org-feed)` is required

Comment: @Jonathan, I can only get this to work on public lists (my password doesn't seem to work) and all of the metadata (tags/dates/etc) are trapped within rss/atom markup. Discussion of my issue is on the org-mode list: http://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg36568.html Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

I realize this is quite old, however a pertinent update is that a Google Summer of Code project is currently in progress to create just this. See (and follow updates to) the page on the Org-mode Wiki for [Org-sync](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/gsoc2012/student-projects/org-sync/).

> **About**
>
> Org-sync is a tool to synchronize your Org-mode documents with bugtracking tools such as Bugzilla, Github or Google Code and other TODO-list services such as Toodledo or Google Task.
>
> **Project Goals**
>
> - Integrate and complete org-element.el
> - Write a library for bugtracker backends
> - Write several backends

There is also a link to the [list of backends](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/gsoc2012/student-projects/org-sync/backends.html) currently in progress to be integrated with Org-sync.

Answer (score 13):

I just save my org-mode files in a Dropbox folder and then they are automatically synced and can be viewed/edited from anywhere.

Comment: how does this help sync with RTM?

Answer (score 9):

This is probably way late but [Sacha Chua](http://sachachua.com/blog/2010/05/org-toodledo/) wrote an org to toodledo synchronization tool for emacs.

http://github.com/sachac/org-toodledo

Answer (score 7):

you could also set up org with some kind of revision control software-- I use git, and then use git to clone/pull where ever i need it.

Answer (score 4):

MobileOrg is, however, limited to the iPhone at present. I am eagerly following development on a similar [application for android](http://github.com/matburt/mobileorg-android).

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility to publish org mode to HTML. If you need only readonly access it should work.

Comment: Hm, that's true. I haven't thought of simple HTML export. That would solve the problem, though I'm still interested in syncing with some webapp in case someday I might want to add/modify tasks too while I'm away from org.

Answer (score 1):

And if memory serves, org-mode has a mobile hook ... here's a snippet from the Info page:

> MobileOrg is an application for the
>   iPhone/iPod Touch series of devices,
>   developed by Richard Moreland. 
>   MobileOrg offers offline viewing and
>   capture support for an Org-mode system
>   rooted on a "real" computer.  It does
>   also allow you to record changes to
>   existing entries.  For information
>   about MobileOrg, see
>   `http://mobileorg.ncogni.to/').
>
> This appendix describes the support
>   Org has for creating agenda views in a
>   format that can be displayed by
>   MobileOrg, and for integrating notes
>   captured and changes made by MobileOrg
>   into the main system.
>
> For changing tags and TODO states
>   in MobileOrg, you should have set up
>   the customization variables
>   `org-todo-keywords' and`
>   org-tags-alist' to cover all
>   important tags and todo keywords, even
>   if individual files use only part of
>   these.  MobileOrg will also offer you
>   states and tags set up with in-buffer
>   settings, but it will understand the
>   logistics of todo state sets (*note
>   Per-file keywords::) and mutually
>   exclusive tags (*note Setting tags::)
>   only for those set in these variables.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't  have a mobile phone which can run MobileOrg. I'd like to check my agenda from any random computer which has net access, that's why I'm looking for a solution which can synchronize with a web application.

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a simple [python script](https://bitbucket.org/edgimar/michel-orgmode) based on some already-existing code,
which allows one to push an org file to a [google-tasks](http://mail.google.com/tasks) list, to
pull the contents of a google-tasks list into an org file, or to perform a bidirectional synchronization between the two.

Answer (score 1):

[org-trello](https://org-trello.github.io/) is a nice package that lets you sync an org-mode file with [Trello](http://trello.com/).

Since Trello's and org-mode's feature sets don't overlap 100 %, I prefer to name the files .trello to make sure I don't confuse them with full-blown org-files.

Here's how I init it, with [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/):

```
(use-package org-trello
  :defer t
  :mode (("\\.trello$" . org-mode))
  :init
  (when (locate-library "org-trello")
    (add-hook 'org-mode-hook
              (defun org-trello-turn-on-if-extension-matches ()
                (let ((filename (buffer-file-name (current-buffer))))
                  (when (and filename (string= "trello" (file-name-extension filename)))
                    (org-trello-mode))))))
  :config
  (set-variable 'org-trello-current-prefix-keybinding "C-c t"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an app for Android, [orgzly](http://www.orgzly.com/), that gives you views of your org-mode files synced by dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally related but `org-mode` doesn't work that well as an 'on-the-go' thing. The mobile-org and other services try to do this but I don't know..

I version control my org files and push them (using `git`) onto my personal webspace and then sync it on the various computers I use. That way, I can keep myself on top of things.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it, but this seems to be an org-mode integration for todoist.com: **https://github.com/ttakamura/org-todoist**

Answer (score 0):

[org-caldav](https://github.com/dengste/org-caldav) has been added a TODO support. It is not perfect¹, but I hope more work will be done on it soon so it becomes a usable option.

¹ For example, it seems to flatten nested TODOs, at least when syncing with the [Netcloud tasks app](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/tasks).